# I am getting a breakpoint and i do not know why

Tags: c++, linked-list, breakpoints, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a priority Queue by using a linked list in c++. However, when I run the program it triggers a breakpoint within "priorityQLinkedList::dequeue()" method. Can someone tell why this is the case and give me suggestions on how to fix it?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

struct DAT
{
    int id;
    char fullname[50];
    double savings; 
};

struct NODE
{
    DAT data; 
    NODE *N; 
    NODE *P;
    NODE(const int i, const char *f, const double s)
    {
        data.id = i;
        strcpy_s(data.fullname, f);
        data.savings = s;
        N = NULL; 
        P = NULL; 
    }
};

class priorityQLinkedList
{
private:
    NODE *front; 
    NODE *back;
public:
    priorityQLinkedList() { front = NULL; back = NULL; }
    ~priorityQLinkedList() { destroyList(); }
    void enqueue(NODE *);
    NODE* dequeue();
    void destroyList(); 
};

void priorityQLinkedList::enqueue(NODE *n)
{
    if (front == NULL) {
        front = n;
        back = n;
    }

    else {
        NODE *temp = front;
        if (n->data.id > temp->data.id)
        {
            front->P = n;
            n->N = front; 
            front = n; 
        }
        else
        {
            //search for the posistion for the new node. 
            while (n->data.id < temp->data.id)
            {
                if (temp->N == NULL) {
                    break; 
                }
                temp = temp->N; 
            }

            //New node id's smallest then all others
            if (temp->N == NULL && n->data.id < temp->data.id)
            {
                back->N = n;
                n->P = back;
                back = n; 
            }

            //New node id's is in the medium range.
            else {
                temp->P->N = n; 
                n->P = temp->P; 
                n->N = temp;
                temp->P = n; 
            }
        }
    }
}

NODE* priorityQLinkedList::dequeue()
{
    NODE *temp; 

    //no nodes
    if (back == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }

    //there is only one node
    else if (back->P == NULL) {
        NODE *temp2 = back; 
        temp = temp2;
        front = NULL;
        back = NULL; 
        delete temp2;
        return temp; 
    }

    //there are more than one node
    else {
        NODE *temp2 = back;
        temp = temp2; 
        back = back->P;
        back->N = NULL;
        delete temp2;
        return temp;
    }

}

void priorityQLinkedList::destroyList()
{
    while (front != NULL) {
        NODE *temp = front; 
        front = front->N;
        delete temp; 
    }
}

void disp(NODE *m) {
    if (m == NULL) {
        cout << "\nQueue is Empty!!!" << endl; 
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nID No.   : " << m->data.id; 
        cout << "\nFull Name    : " << m->data.fullname; 
        cout << "\nSalary   : " << setprecision(15) << m->data.savings << endl; 
    }
}

int main() {
    priorityQLinkedList *Queue = new priorityQLinkedList();

    NODE No1(101, "Qasim Imtiaz", 567000.0000);
    NODE No2(102, "Hamad Ahmed", 360200.0000);
    NODE No3(103, "Fahad Ahmed", 726000.0000); 
    NODE No4(104, "Usmaan Arif", 689000.0000); 

    Queue->enqueue(&No4); 
    Queue->enqueue(&No3);
    Queue->enqueue(&No1);
    Queue->enqueue(&No2); 

    disp(Queue->dequeue());
    disp(Queue->dequeue());
    disp(Queue->dequeue());
    disp(Queue->dequeue()); 
    disp(Queue->dequeue());

    delete Queue; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I be mistaken, but if you `delete` the node to be dequeued and then return a pointer to the same, wouldn't this cause problems for the caller, who would then be getting back a "dead" pointer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is what is happening, u should write it as answer

Comment: @AndersK. I attempted an answer below.  I didn't see a nice way of handling this, but certainly I think `dequeue()` should be removing the target node.  My answer was to make a copy of `NODE` and return to the caller.  But then the caller would have to call `delete` at some point.

Comment: yes ownership in this code is hard to see. would be better to use smart pointers, then the function could return a shared pointer instead.

Answer (score 1):

One problem which stands out in your `dequeue()` method is that you are calling `delete` on a `NODE` pointer, and then attempting to return this deleted pointer to the caller.  This could cause an error either in `dequeue()` itself, or certainly in the caller who thinks he is getting back a pointer to an actual live `NODE` object.

One potential fix would be to create a copy of the `NODE` being dequeued.  You would still remove the target from your list, but the caller would then be returned a valid pointer, which he could free later.

```
NODE* priorityQLinkedList::dequeue()
{
    NODE *temp; 

    // no nodes
    if (back == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }

    NODE *temp2 = back; 
    temp = new NODE(temp2->data.id, temp2->data.fullname, temp2->data.savings);

    // there is only one node
    else if (back->P == NULL) {
        front = NULL;
        back = NULL; 
        delete temp2;
        return temp; 
    }

    // there are more than one node
    else {
        back = back->P;
        back->N = NULL;
        delete temp2;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming that the `priorityQLinkedList` owns the node pointers.  It does not.  They are passed in to `enqueue` and are owned by the caller of `enqueue`.  This solution will not solve OP's problem.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Please edit my answer and fix it.  I'm not a C++ guru, but returning a deleted pointer has smell to me.  Wish I knew more about C++.

Answer (score 1):

You're deleting pointers in `dequeue` that `priorityQLinkedList` does not own, so you don't know if it is safe to delete them.

In this case, they are not since the node pointers passed to `enqueue` are addresses of local, stacked based variables and have not been allocated by `new`.  (There's also the already mentioned problem of deleting a pointer then returning it, which is Undefined Behavior.)

The fix for the code as shown is to remove the calls to `delete` in `dequeue`.  However, if changes are made so that the nodes passed to `enqueue` are dynamically allocated, you'll need to add something to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

1.First change strcpy_s to strcpy is struct NODE.

2.Instead of Delete(temp2) use temp2--.

```
//no nodes
if (back == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}

//there is only one node
else if (back->P == NULL) {
    NODE *temp2 = back;
    temp = temp2;
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    temp2--;
    return temp;
}

//there are more than one node
else {
    NODE *temp2 = back;
    temp = temp2;
    back = back->P;
    back->N = NULL;
    temp2--;
    return temp;
}
```

I hope this will resolve the problem.